# Runas admin (from batch script/cmd) not working properly

Tags: c#, sharepoint, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to get a batch script to run a silent install of my program. Here's the line that's causing trouble:

```
runas /user:domain\admin /savecred start "" "%temp%\MyProgram - 4.6.0.0\Setup.exe" /silent >> %userprofile%\Desktop\BatchLog.txt
```

A few notes:

- `""` before the file location is there to avoid issues with spaces in the location of `Setup.exe`
- `/silent` is a parameter passed into `Setup.exe` to run a silent installation
- `>> %userprofile%\Desktop\BatchLog.txt` pipes the output to a log file

When run as part of a batch script, `Setup.exe` isn't running as `domain\admin`. For the SharePoint savvy, `SPFarm.Local` is throwing a `null ref` (it's written in C#), indicating that the running user doesn't have DB access. Can you spot anything wrong with my use of `runas` here?

Running that line from the command line just pulls up the `runas` help screen. I'd like to find out why that's happening as well.

If I just manually run (double-click) `Setup.exe` (logged in as `domain\admin`) I don't get that `null ref`, indicating that my program is running properly as `domain\admin`.

How can I fix this line to execute my program as `domain\admin`?

Comment: Think that the whole command needs to be in quotes as runas only takes 1 "program" parameter. Also, the start command doesn't seem compatible with runas.  Try this: runas /user:domain\admin /savecred "\"%temp%\MyProgram - 4.6.0.0\Setup.exe\" /silent >> \"%userprofile%\Desktop\BatchLog.txt\""

Comment: @Egg I'll try that syntax and get back to you.

Comment: @Egg That ignores the silent parameter.

Comment: @Egg Nevermind, it's an issue with the Setup, not the command. Thank you.

Comment: @Egg If you would like to add that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think that the whole command needs to be in quotes as runas only takes 1 "program" parameter. Also, the start command doesn't seem compatible with runas. Try this:

```
runas /user:domain\admin /savecred "\"%temp%\MyProgram - 4.6.0.0\Setup.exe\" /silent >> \"%userprofile%\Desktop\BatchLog.txt\""
```